# Cannot access textLabel value when deleting cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

Ok so I am a beginner and I have created a UITableView with a custom cell class that loads as it should, displaying 2 textLabels (`cellPrice` and `cellTitle`) in each row/cell (all working fine).

But the issue is when i call the delete row function, I cannot access the values of the textLabels. I get the same error when calling both labels - value of type `UITableViewCell`? has no member `cellPrice`'

I cannot work out why when the cell labels and values load ok and are correct but i cannot access them when i need to delete them. Please see my code below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        self.total - self.dict[tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath).​cellPrice!.text‌​!]
        self.totalLabel.text = "Total: \(self.total)"
        self.dict.removeValueForKey(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath).cellTitle!.text!)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }             
}
```

Comment: Get the info of label BEFORE you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to cast the cell to your custom class:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCustomCellClass
self.total - self.dict[cell.​cellPrice!.text‌​!]
```

Comment: Minor suggestion, but better to use `guard let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? MyCustomCellClass else { return }` so it doesn't crash if other cell types are introduced in the future.

Comment: @V.Roberts Maybe it's giving you the error on the other line?

Comment: I amended the other line as well, there is now only the one error on line -  'self.total - self.dict[cell.​cellPrice!.text‌​!]' with same error ?

Comment: Value of type 'myCustomCell' has no member 'cellPrice'

Comment: @V.Roberts Could you share the code of your `myCustomCell` with us?

Comment: This is my class -

Comment: class myCustomCell:UITableViewCell {
     IBOutlet weak var cellTitle: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var cellPrice: UILabel!
}

Comment: TableView delegate -  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: myCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCustomCell
        var myDataSource : [String] = Array(self.dict.keys)
        let key = myDataSource[indexPath.row] as String
        cell.cellTitle?.text = myDataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellPrice?.text = "£\(self.dict[key]!)"
        self.saveState()
        return cell

    }

Comment: Ok so by doing this - self.total = self.cost - self.dict[cell.cellPrice.text!]! The error goes away but now the app crashes as it cannot execute that line as its finding that label NIL. I know its not nil because i can see the cellPrice before i delete it. Why would that be?

Comment: @V.Roberts Either the `text` is `nil` (you can unwrap using `?? ""` instead of `!`) or there is nothing in `self.dict` for the given key.

Comment: If i change that line to anything else i get errors. But surely it can't be nil if i can visibly see a value displayed in that cell label when i swipe to delete it?

Comment: @V.Roberts `text` doesn't have to be `nil` but the value in the dictionary can be `nil`.

Comment: Ok. Could you suggest a way round it?

Comment: When i call self.dict in the debugger it tells me that there is an element stored in there